# A better alternative to "taking out pomegranate seeds by hands"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs, synonyms

Today, I found the usage of the verb "peel" in [OffSet](https://www.offset.com/photos/mans-hands-peeling-a-pomegranate-close-up-646535) site, which says:

> Man's hands **peeling** a pomegranate.

I am sure that "peel" can easily be used in "peeling potatoes", as we strip off their outer layer (skin in general). But in sense of **taking out** pomegranate seeds, I am confused ... wether to use "peel" or not.

People often use the phrasal verb, as in:

> Man's hands **spooning out** the pomegranate seeds.

But saying "spooning out ..." will totally be wrong, if the man uses his hands, rather than a spoon.

Is there any other way to describe the image given below.

> A man _____ the pomegranate seeds.
>
> [image: picture of water pouring into a glass]

Comment: Pomegranates are not peeled. They are cut in half and the seeds removed for consumption,

Comment: There are many ways to open and deseed a pomegranate. Some are more like peeling than others, and not all involve halving the fruit. Google it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**to seed**   [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174755?rskey=5fPd09&result=2#eid)

> transitive. To remove the seeds from (a plant, fruit, etc.), to
>   deseed

As in:

[How To Seed a Pomegranate the Easy Way](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-seed-a-pomegranate-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-182342)

and your example:

> A man seeds a pomegranate.

To **deseed** is acceptable too.

Comment: No, because deseed means you throw out the seeds. Here, they will be consumed.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that he is ***extracting*** the seeds.  I'm not a pomegranate eater, but from what I've seen it's a little more challenging than just *taking out* the seeds and it seems it would be difficult to get a spoon in there to *spoon* them out.

From the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[extract](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extract)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Remove or take out, especially by effort or force.
>
>    *‘the fossils are extracted from the chalk’*
>
>    1.1 Obtain (a substance or resource) from something by a special method.
>
>    *‘lead was extracted from the copper’*

The *especially by effort or force* part of definition 1 seems appropriate, as does the *special method* part of definition 1.1.

Comment: You can spoon them out if you loosen them first. Nobody here seems to have ever handled a pomegranate.

Answer (score 0):

Shuck? Often used with corn but it means to remove husk... not sure what a husk exactly is.